# Cleaning up low quality posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are a lot of low quality posts about issues that can be resolved by following guides that are already present on the StackExchange. In addition, there's a lot of questions pertaining to similar topics (e.g. MyMonero not working properly). In my opinion, it clutters the StackExchange and lowers the overall quality of it. Can the mods please clean it up?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for my recent absence. I had not logged in for several days and acknowledge the problem. Flagging the questions as duplicates (as you and others have done) can help expedite the process (by easing moderation prioritization) when the mod queue gets longer than normal.

In the future hopefully we wont have long absences of mods logging in, but with 5 or more votes from those with 500+ Monero SE reputation, these type of questions [can still be closed](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)